# Can a javascript function run in setTimeout callback only?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

This is the question:

Define a function named `print` which just print out the parameters it gets.

But it will not print out anything if it's called normally.

Only in a setTimeout callback will become effective.

e.g:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    print('123'); //===> 123
});

print('456'); //===> nothing output
```

I have one solution but I don't think it's a good way, I rewrite the setTimeout.

I want a better solution curiously.

```
var print = function() {
    'use strict';
    var __origSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;

    window.setTimeout = function(fn, delay) {
        var _fn = new Function(`(${fn.toString().replace(/print\(/g, 'print.call(this,')}).call(this);`);
        return __origSetTimeout.call(window, _fn.bind({
            isFromSetTimeout: true
        }), delay);
    };

    return function print(word) {
        if (!this || !!this && !this.isFromSetTimeout) return;
        console.log(word);
    };
}.call(null);
```

Comment: Not possible. You would either have to define a context or pass different params so the function knows whether it should or should not output.

Comment: No. Maybe you are looking for something else, why would you want this functionality?

Comment: Save the id of the timeout and use that.

Comment: This really looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you attempting to solve by doing this?

Comment: If you require a timeout for some reason, why not wrap the function's contents in a timeout?

Comment: This looks like a homework or an interview question rather than a real life programming problem (doesn't make it bad question, IMHO). First of all, this definitely needs to be scoped, `print` is a native function in `window`, which you shouldn't override. With an outer scope you have more alternatives for referring objects.

Comment: @Teemu Yes, this is an interview question I found in a technical discussion group.I will not deliberately work to solve the problem that seems to be meaningless when I am working. Just some curiosity

Answer (score 0):

You can use scope to solve this, for example

```js
function A(){
    let print = function(str){
        console.log(str);
    }
    this.setTimeout = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            print('123');
        }, 1000);
    }
}


let a = new A();
a.setTimeout();
```

Comment: it won't, it is a private function

Answer (score 0):

You could use a monkey patch for an extension of the `print` function with an additional check for a this object and a property for printing.

```js
// simple function with output
function print(s) {
    console.log(s);
}

// apply monkey patch
void function () {
    var p = print;
    print = function () {
        if (this && this.timeout) {
            p.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
}();

 // bind additional information
setTimeout(print.bind({ timeout: true }, '123'));
 
print('456');
```